# How to easily get password from authinfo.gpg

Tags: gnupg

Once gpg installed and configured, it can be used for variety of things. I even learned how to keep arbitrary data encrypted for my applications, I can easily do something like this:

```
gpg2 -q --for-your-eyes-only --no-tty -d ~/my-encrypted-file.gpg
```

One thing I can't figure out though, there's gotta be an idiomatic way of retrieving passwords from authinfo.gpg, right?

So let's say I want to have a script that mounts an external drive to some remote machine (let's call it 'beefy-server'), but I don't want to expose the uname/password. If I keep it encrypted in authinfo.gpg
in standardized form:

```
machine beefy-server login admin password foobar1030
```

I can of course, do:

```
gpg2 -q --for-your-eyes-only --no-tty -d ~/.authinfo.gpg
```

and then pipe it to awk, sed and whatnot, right now I'm doing it like this:

```
gpg2 -q --for-your-eyes-only --no-tty -d ~/.authinfo.gpg \
| grep beefy-server \
| sed -e "s/.*password\(.*\).*$/\1/"
```

But is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the conventioned way to pipe gpg output through awk is

```
gpg2 -q --for-your-eyes-only --no-tty -d ~/.authinfo.gpg | awk '/machine beefy-server login yourname/ {print $NF}'
```

where it is assumed that you have a line in authinfo.gpg that has details of the beefy-server and the password at the end. Like so

```
machine beefy-server login yourname port 465 password myverysecretpassword
```

Comment: Don't you need to complete your regex with a closing `/` ? Something like `awk '/machine beefy-server login yourname/ {print $NF}'`

Comment: @L.Grozinger Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated the answer accordingly :-)